# how to change bootstrap card-header value with java script?

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-4

I have a ejs(html) file, and There is a div class called "card".
What I want to do is that, if I click the button("Click me") then,
card-header(header1) has to be changed(before --> after) with colored back-ground. 
However when I clicked the button, only the back-ground color was changed (excluding the header). need your help.

```js
     function save() {
        var x = document.getElementById("header1");
        x.style.backgroundColor="#cfe8f9";
        x.setAttribute("value", "After");
    }
```

```html
     <div class="col-sm-6">
            <div class="card">
              <div class="card-header" id="header1" style="font-weight:bold;">before</div>
              <div class="card-body">
                <form action="" method="POST">
                  <input type="hidden" id="input_flag" value="">
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="input-group">
                      <div class="input-group-prepend">
                        <span class="input-group-text">noID</span>
                      </div>
                      <input type="text" id="notiSeq_1" name="notiSeq_1" class="form-control" value="" style="background-color:#FFFFFF">
                      <div class="input-group-append">
                        <span class="input-group-text">
                          <i class="fa fa-sort-numeric-asc"></i>
                        </span>
                       ...
                       ...
                       ...
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick ="save()">Click me</button>
     </div> //end of col-sm-6
```

Comment: When you say change the value, did you mean text? Values and attributes are additional information about an element, and are usually not visible on screen. Rather it is the content in between the opening and closing tag of an element that would be displayed. Replace `x.setAttribute("value", "After");` with `x.innerHTML = "After";`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update the innerHTML

```js
function save() {
        var x = document.getElementById("header1");
        x.style.backgroundColor="#cfe8f9";
        x.innerHTML = "After";
    }
```

```html
<div class="col-sm-6">
            <div class="card">
              <div class="card-header" id="header1" style="font-weight:bold;">before</div>
              <div class="card-body">
                <form action="" method="POST">
                  <input type="hidden" id="input_flag" value="">
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="input-group">
                      <div class="input-group-prepend">
                        <span class="input-group-text">noID</span>
                      </div>
                      <input type="text" id="notiSeq_1" name="notiSeq_1" class="form-control" value="" style="background-color:#FFFFFF">
                      <div class="input-group-append">
                        <span class="input-group-text">
                          <i class="fa fa-sort-numeric-asc"></i>
                        </span>
                       ...
                       ...
                       ...
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick ="save()">Click me</button>
     </div> //end of col-sm-6
```